# Alamofire crash in session.swift deinit:

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, alamofire, crashlytics

I am working on the Swift project and I have used the alamofire for handling the network. This crash only occurred in 14.6.0 and above the OS versions. I have attached the code below for creating/cancel session:

Session create:

```
func sessionManager() -> Session {   
    //SSL pining
        instantiateTrustKit()
        if let manage = self.manager {
            return manage
        }
        else {
            let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
            self.manager = Session(configuration: configuration, delegate: CustomDelegate())
            guard let sessionManager = manager else {
                return Session.default
            }
            return sessionManager
        }
    }
```

Cancel ongoing request:

```
func cancelAllRequests() {
        sessionManager().session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks in
            dataTasks.forEach {
                $0.cancel() }
            uploadTasks.forEach {
                $0.cancel() }
            downloadTasks.forEach {
                $0.cancel() }
        }
}



Crash Stack trace:     Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x25dd0 objc_release + 16
1  Alamofire                      0xb4b90 Session.deinit + 204 (Session.swift:204)
2  Alamofire                      0xb4c2c Session.__deallocating_deinit + 202 (Session.swift:202)
3  libswiftCore.dylib             0x383c98 _swift_release_dealloc + 40
4  libswiftCore.dylib             0x384b90 bool swift::HeapObjectSideTableEntry::decrementStrong<(swift::PerformDeinit)1>(unsigned int) + 288
```

1. While sending requests we called the **sessionManager** function to get the current session.
2. When the user opens the app for the first time and the user navigates to the main screen the **cancel request** function will be called.

Could anyone know the above issue?

Comment: What's the crash message?

Comment: session.swift deinit: @Cristik

Comment: That's the whole message? No SIGSEGV, or other signals?

Comment: @Cristik
Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000dd6c731a0
Session.deinit

Comment: any idea @Cristik

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` usually indicates invalid memory accesses, given the fact that the crash happens on a background queue, it might be related to data races. But it's hard to pinpoint the exact cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to Xcode menu “Product” » “Scheme” » “Edit Scheme...” » “Run” » “Diagnostics” and turn on “Address Sanitizer” and the “Detect use of stack after return”, it will help you identify and resolve these issues in the future:

[image]

Comment: In my case, the problem was an async-await task in `deinit`, but yours is likely a different scenario, possibly from where you called `cancelAllRequests`. But the above helped me find and quickly resolve my particular scenario.